# How to call DMN in another DMN?

Tags: quarkus, dmn, kogito

I have a DMN which calculates (a common unit of work), which I want to plug-in in another DMN. Is there an example for this in kogito examples?

Can someone help me to get me an example.

Comment: Have you tried any example of DMN importing other DMN(s) as per the construct of the DMN standard? They should work just fine on Kogito too. Please bear in mind the standalone Kogito DMN editor might not support Import just yet, but the underlying runtime does. So placing in a Kogito project DMN asset with Import would achieve what you are after. If not please report the bug. Thanks!

Comment: let me try and get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no example.

**Included models are not supported** on DMN editor when it's running on the **[online version](http://dmn.new)** or the **VSCode** version. This feature will be available soon, so you can keep track of this by looking at [KOGITO-697](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-697).

However, **Included models are supported** on DMN editor when it's running on **Business Central**. So you can create your models there, and execute them on Kogito (just for now) - as @tarilabs said, the runtime already supports it.